# POM errors in transition from M2E 0.12 to 0.13

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I am getting this infamous maven 0.13 error out of a simple basic POM.

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources
>   (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>ABC</groupId>
 <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

This POM was created by M2E itself when I clicked Maven:Enable dependency!
And it is flagging a pom that it created itself as invalid? It's an empty POM, for goodness' sake.

Q1. What do I have to do to make this basic empty pom valid?

Q2. Why did authors of m2e not update their template pom generator so that m2e 0.13 generates a template POM that is compliant to its own requirements?

Q2 is a curiosity but Q1 needs an answer badly.

Comment: Move to m2e 1.0 and don't bother with this.

Comment: Thx margulies. m2e 1.0 solved the problem. If you had supplied your comment as an answer I would have checked it as the answer.

Comment: I was afraid that you had a special reason for staying back at 0.x.

Comment: well, why don't you make it an answer, so that I could conclude the question by flagging an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Indigo comes with M2E 1.0, which does not complain. Though it is always a good idea with m2e to explicitly call out version 2.5 of the maven-resources-plugin in your `<pluginManagement/>` element.